# Opening multiple terminal tabs and running command

Tags: bash, scripts, gnome-terminal, rails, rvm

I need to open multiple terminal tabs, give them titles, go to a directory, and make each tab run a command.

I am new to Linux and shell scripting, after searching online and checking some solutions, I made this script (**EDITED** based on answers below):

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /media/Extra/Project

tab=" --tab-with-profile=Default"
options=(--tab --title=Terminal)

cmds[1]="'rails s'"
titles[1]="Server"

cmds[2]="'rails c'"
titles[2]="Console"


for i in 1 2; do
  options+=($tab --title="${titles[i]}"  -e "bash -c \"${cmds[i]} ; bash\"" )          
done

gnome-terminal "${options[@]}"


exit 0
```

It opens the tabs, names them, but fail to execute the commands generating this error:

> There was an error creating the child process for this terminal

Another shortcoming is that if I halted the running command it closes the tab, which I don't want. I need to be able to stop the command and run it again within the same tab.

What is wrong with the script? Is there another simpler way to do that?

> Note: If I removed the (-e "\"bash -c ${cmds[i]} ;bash\"") part from the command, it opens the tabs in the given directory and name them, with no errors.

## -Edit-1:

After applying @Tuknutx answer below and editing the script, the error doesn't appear anymore, but it gives me `bash: rails c: command not found` and `rails s` creates a new rails app instead of starting the rails server, I am using .rmvrc to select a gemset once this folder is accessed.

Comment: If you want to make your script run on your ubuntu boot:
- you can run you script as an upstart service(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto)
or: using "startup applications" in your desktop environment

Comment: if i write `cmds[1]="'ping 192.168.9.9'"` it gives me the same error but i resolved it by removing single quotation. So if i write `cmds[1]="ping 192.168.9.9"` It works.

Comment: @Brary but i don't understand why it opens three tabs-one default and another two that set in script. Because we define `tab=" --tab-with-profile=Default"` ??

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `tmux` with [`tmuxinator`](https://goo.gl/aaFFl8), it will does the job for you, and you can rely on `terminator` layouts too!

For `terminator` layout checkout mhnagaoka's answer [here](http://goo.gl/21I6wV) askubuntu too:

> 1. After setting up your layout, right-click on any terminal background and choose **Preferences** → **Layouts** tab and click on
>      **Add** button.
> 2. Give it a name and hit **Close**.
> 3. This should create the mentioned `~/.config/terminator/config` file.
> 4. Now you can start terminator using the saved layout using: `terminator -l yourLayout` (replace *yourLayout* with whatever you
>      chose on step 2).
> 5. **(optional)** Edit the `~/.config/terminator/config` file so that where it says `[layouts]` and nested below it `[[yourLayout]]`, rename
>      *yourLayout* to *default* and remove/rename the previous *default* layout. Now, when Terminator starts without any parameters, it will
>      load your custom `[[default]]` layout!

Answer (score 3):

To summarize a couple of the other answers and their comments, here is what I ended up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /path/of/my/stuff

tab=" --tab"
options=()

cmds[1]="echo Banana"

cmds[2]="echo Cat"


for i in 1 2; do
options+=($tab -e "bash -c '${cmds[i]} ; bash'" )
done

gnome-terminal "${options[@]}"

exit 0
```

Note that I took away the 'master' tab, and the profiles, and the titles (which appear to be deprecated in `gnome-terminal`).

Comment: The output of `$tab -e...`  `Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.`
` Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.`. that's an output but the comands get executed. When i use `$tab -- ` the command doesn't get executed and the terminal dsisplays: `There was an error creating the child process for this terminal.  Failed to execute child process “bash -c 'echo Banana ; bash'” (No such file or directory)`

Answer (score 1):

The argument you're giving the -e option is `"bash -c command; bash"` including the quotes.  It interprets that whole string as the name of a command!  Try this instead: `-e "bash -c 'command ; bash'"`.  This way what gets run on your terminal window is  `command`, and after that runs, you're given a daughter shell, which I assume is what you want.  Incidentally, you can also say `'command & bash'`; this will run the command on the background and give you the daughter shell right away.

Comment: I changed this `options+=($tab --title="${titles[i]}"  -e "\"bash -c ${cmds[i]} ;bash\"" )` into `options+=($tab --title="${titles[i]}"  -e "\"bash -c '${cmds[i]} ;bash'\"" )` and it gave me the same error .. am I doing it right?

Comment: Not quite correct: remove \" before the first bash and \" after the ' after the second bash.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question and changed the scope of it to include rails and rvm.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
options+=($tab --title="${titles[i]}"  -e "bash -c \"${cmds[i]} ; bash\"" )
```

otherwise the whole expression after -e will be interpreted as the command.

To include aliases from .bashrc use `-ic` instead of `c`

Comment: The error doesn't appear anymore, thanks. But it gives me `bash: rails c: command not found` and 'rails s' creates a new rails app instead of starting the rails server. This changes the scope of the question, I will edit it with ur modification for the script

Comment: Did it work if you try `rails c` on a terminal without anything else? Perhaps it should be `rails -c` ?

Comment: Tried that didn't work. I even tried `rvm list gemsets` and it says `No command 'rvm' found` .. run the same command `rvm list gemsets` in the first tab that opens without running a command and it worked! does it run the command before the environment loads and the .rvmrc file is loaded?